# How can I retry a code block on non-infrastructure related errors in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins pipelines provide a [retry step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) that re-executes code in case of an error.
The optional `conditions` parameter allows the value `agent` which re-executes errors that are "likely due to infrastructure rather than the behavior of the build".

I need to handle the exact opposite case, i.e. errors that occur due to the behavior of the build and are **not** infrastructure-related.

Is there an easy way to do that?

I tried

1. to negate the condition, e.g. `retry(conditions: [!agent()], count: 3)`, but the retry step expects an object of class `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.ErrorCondition`, not a boolean.
2. to implement a custom class that inherits from  `ErrorCondition`, delegates to an object of type [AgentErrorCondition](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-durable-task-step/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/AgentErrorCondition.html) in the test method and returns the negated result, but this did not work as expected - Maybe that can only be done in a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your build fails with an error when there is a faulty `behavior of the build`. In that case just remove the condition in the retry, if you want to do retries on a specific error add an additional condition in the catch block.

```
retry(2) {
    try {
       // Do your stuff
    } catch(err) {
         // If you want to check addidional error types do here
        if(err.getMessage().contains("something")) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```